# JQuery Tooltipster hiding element it's attached to

Tags: javascript, jquery, tooltip, tooltipster

I am trying to use JQuery Tooltipster in my Asp.net MVC application.

The content I am trying t add the tooltip to is generated dynamically through JavaScript.

View:

```
    var engName = document.getElementsByClassName("dhx_matrix_scell");
    for (var i = 0; i < engName.length; i++) {
        engName[i].className = engName[i].className + " tooltip";
        engName[i].title = "Hello";
    }
```

top of my index:

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
    $('.tooltip').tooltipster(
    {
         multiple: true
    });
});
```

The tooltip does work, but it doesn't appear in the right spot, and it doesnt display the element that uses the tooltip class.

Pic for reference: 
[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

so I figured out my problem!
I was also using a Bootstrap.css link in my project as well, and there was a mismatch between the class names "tooltip"

I changed the name to "tooltips" and it initialized it as such, and it worked flawlessly!

Comment: Same for me, changed the class on the image to tooltips as mentioned and also changed $('.tooltips').tooltipster(); in my document ready method